# SQL Server Database ID Change

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a job that has been running successfully for approximately a year now which drops and recreates database snapshots of our production database 2x per day.

To make sure I was always dropping the correct snapshot, I would check both it's name and the source ID's value.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = N'BLAH_815PM' AND source_database_id = 10
```

This has suddenly started failing over the last four days. When I investigated, I found that the source_database_id was no longer 10 but had changed to 9. One of the database snapshots had taken on the ID of 10. Now the below line runs.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = N'BLAH_815PM' AND source_database_id = 9
```

How is it even possible for a database ID to change and is this indicative of other problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We believe that we identified the cause to this. We use 2 different types of backups in house. The primary backup is using a SnapManager (a NetApp SAN solution) and the second is traditional copy only full backups. We did a SnapManager restore  of the source database late last week. Apparently that process changed its database id.

I've restored this same database using traditional backups without issue so I'm guessing that this is something implicit in SnapManager method.

I cannot find any documentation of "bad things" that happen if the database id changes. I'm going to assume that it's a non-issue.